# Interpolating image from irregular grid

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, interpolation

I have an irregular grid of coordinates coming from a projected 640x480 image, all of which have rgb values. I am trying to form an image from these points. I have tried several interpolation methods, none of which were good enough.

1. Scipy.interpolate.rbf: memory complexity too high to be used with images ( O(n^2) )
2. scipy.interpolate.griddata: too slow, i need at least 4 fps on raspberry pi 4
3. using a k-d tree and  assigning every pixel to its closest neighbor: barely fast enough on laptop, wont work on raspberry pi 4

Is there a faster method i can use (doesnt need to be terribly precise, nearest-neighbor precision is fine)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did that exactly happen, the "irregular grid"?

Comment: i project an image from a quadcopter onto the z=0 plane. This yields a trapezoidal grid

Comment: that's a homography. that's not "irregular". use OpenCV and warpPerspective